# Get all registered Users into a Field Type List

Tags: entities, users, tokens

I would like to create a content/form where an authenticated user is able to choose another registered user from a list/dropdown. I've been searching for ways to get this done but am not able to find any working solution. Token can only display current-user, not all users. I can list all users using Views but not able to import them into the field of type list.

ie:
Nomination Form
Favorite Sport : [options](list from taxonomy)[/options]
Favorite Users : [options](list of all registered users)[/options]
etc

Appreciate if someone can point out what I am missing. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create form using [Entity form](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityform).
It provides interface you to fetch content from the drupal fields taxonomy and other fields.
Term reference is inbuilt in drupal to add the Sports list.

For user reference list you can add the [references module](https://www.drupal.org/project/references) which will ask you to choose users from the registered users.

Hope it will help you